# Problems with double .get() in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm working with a nested dictionary were the entries looks like this:

```
net_info = {
            '17052242':{'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2,
                        'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532},
            '21009006':{'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528,'uparea': 493.8188826654188,
                        'order': 2,'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623},
            .
            .
            .
             }
```

Here is a line of code where I look for a key and a feature inside the dictionary using a double .get(). It works like a charm except when it can't find the key... I know it is because it is passing 0 as a key to the next .get(). My question is, is there a way to just return 0 if it can't find the key and not pass it to the next .get()?

```
unitarea_max = max(net_dictionary.get(in1,0).get('unitarea',0), \
net_dictionary.get(in2,0).get('unitarea',0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a dictionary to the next `.get()`. Since it's an empty dictionary you'll get the default from the second `.get()`.

```
net_dictionary.get(in1,{}).get('unitarea',0)
```

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `NestedDict`. First install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```

Then

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

net_info = {
    '17052242': {
        'lengthkm': 1.555787,
        'uparea': 123.23709555834532,
        'order': 2,
        'strmDrop_t': 231.5,
        'unitarea': 123.23709555834532
    },
    '21009006': {
        'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528,
        'uparea': 493.8188826654188,
        'order': 2,
        'strmDrop_t': 5.3,
        'unitarea': 36.89608111068623
    }
}

nd = NestedDict(net_info)

zero = nd.get(("wrong key", "unitarea"), 0)
```